# "Connection closed" accessing neo4j in Docker from node.js in Docker on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, neo4j

I'm running a neo4j database as well as an node.js api in a Docker container. On startup, the api tries to import a lot of data into neo4j, accessing it through neo4-driver. I can also run those imports manually from inside the Docker container or outside (locally).

This used to work fine. It works fine on Windows, it works fine for other people using a Macbook, and *sometimes* it also works for me, but then the connection mysteriously drops and I only get `ECONNREFUSED` errors anymore, until I restart the container. Neither neo4j nor Docker give any indication that anything is wrong. Nothing in the logs, they don't seem to have crashed, they're just inaccessible. The neo4j browser interface on port 7474 is also gone, though it used to be there.

The fact that this sometimes works is the baffling part. But it never works for long, before I get the errors again. When it drops, I often (not always) first get an `EPIPE` error.

I used to run Docker/docker desktop 3.1 and 10.20.2, now upgraded to 3.6.0 and 10.20.8. Neo4j version 3. The api runs on Alpine.

I use `docker-compose -p 7687:7687 -f ./docker-compose.yml up` to start Docker, and my docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  neo4j:
    build:
      context: ./db/
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"

  api:
    build:
      context: ./api/
    volumes:
      - ./api/:/code/
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I execute queries to neo4j with:

```
const session = driver.session();
session.writeTransaction((tx) => tx.run(query, params))
```

where `driver` was previously initialized with

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(neo4jUrl, neo4j.auth.basic(user, passwd), {});
```

The most common error is this:

```
Neo4jError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:7687

  at captureStacktrace (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/result.js:199:15)
  at new Result (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/result.js:65:19)
  at _newRunResult (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/transaction.js:354:10)
  at Object.run (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/transaction.js:238:14)
  at Transaction.run (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/transaction.js:104:26)
  ...
  at TransactionExecutor._safeExecuteTransactionWork (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/transaction-executor.js:134:22)
  at TransactionExecutor._executeTransactionInsidePromise (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/transaction-executor.js:122:32)
  at Timeout._onTimeout (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/transaction-executor.js:98:18)
  at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17) {
code: 'ServiceUnavailable'
```

I suspect it might have something to do with Docker differences between Windows and Mac, but I'm not sure. It has also worked fine with other Mac users, and occasionally does work for me, just not for long. So what could cause this connection to suddenly drop?

Comment: Why do you need `-p 7687:7687` in your `docker-compose` command? I think it is redundant.

Comment: I agree it looks redundant, and I don't think I needed it on Windows, but on Mac I think it did solve a problem. But I'll try it without it. Although I doubt it hurts.

Comment: Could it be an issue with the amount of ram you give to your container ? At some point the neo4j starve and crash/stop processing request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems more related to your environment than containers.

Could you check :

- Computers resources available : RAM and CPU

  > You can limit CPU/RAM usage of a container with docker-compose --compatibility

  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy

  ```yaml
  services:
    app:
      ...
      deploy:
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2g
            cpus: '1.4'
  ```
- OS version : Containers share kernel with your OS, an old kernel (or brand new) may have effects on your containers.
- Docker version : This process runs your containers, you've upgraded it however.
- Network : I've had and issue where IP used by my container was in conflict with an existing one, your can force an ip for your container.

  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ipam

  ```yaml
  services:
    app:
      networks:
        - backend

  networks:
    backend:
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: "10.8.0.0/24"
  ```

#### EDIT 1

EPIPE error could be the main issue in fact.

Could you try to increase resource limits in docker desktop ?

`Docker Desktop -> Settings -> Resources -> Advanced`

#### EDIT 2

It is normal that you are not able to find neo4j hostname from your host.

- Neo4j run inside a container
- `neo4j` hostname is a docker mechanism working for other containers in the same docker network.
- outside docker, try to connect to `localhost` instead or `127.0.0.1`
- regarding your compose file, ports are already exposed.

Comment: I haven't set any limits on Docker anywhere that I know of. Is it possible that Mac has different defaults that break this? Can I check? OS X version is 11.5.2, Docker versions are in the post. It's definitely possible it has something to do with my network; I'm on a corporate VPN that works differently for Windows and Mac. I generally try not to touch network netup, because I assume the defaults are better than anything I could set it to, but I'll have a look at this.

Comment: @mcv, to monitor your resources, you may use `docker ps` (it will show cpu/ram usage). regarding your network, first, stop your container (docker-compose down), then try to check if IP is already in use (as you're in a corporate network, some protocols could be closed, but nmap, or a simple ping should be enough).

Comment: `docker ps` does not show cpu/ram use: 
e46d89988170   76877687_api     "/bin/sh -c 'until n…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp                                                                  76877687_api_1
75bf3e77d4d5   76877687_neo4j   "/sbin/tini -g -- /d…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   6362/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, :::7474->7474/tcp, 7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp, :::7687->7687/tcp   76877687_neo4j_1

Comment: Accessing neo4j from outside I get `Neo4jError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND neo4j` on Mac, despite setting all the right ports open, and this working fine on Win. But something did change: now, when I log into the docker container, I can run my imports from there, and now it can reach outside sources, which it couldn't before. All I did was a `down` and `up`. Although I am currently not working from home, so it's possible that that's still a factor. Still, I can't reach neo4j from outside docker.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, could you check my answer, edit 2. I hope it will be solved then.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out where I'd be using neo4j as hostname instead of locahost, but it turns out the script I'm running uses a configuration file with this line: `'neo4j-local': process.env.NEO4J_HOST ? `bolt://${process.env.NEO4J_HOST}:${process.env.NEO4J_PORT}` : 'bolt://neo4j:7687',`. So I should have simply set that env variable. Or maybe use locahost as the default, because all Docker containers set their own environment.